# Zend Mail - Email is not sent

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

I have a problem sending a registration email via zend_mail. The mail is transmitted only to mails that have a @gmail.com.

```
$email = "test@gmx.net";
$mail = new Zend_Mail ();
$mail->setBodyText ( 'some text' );
$mail->setBodyHtml ( 'some text' );
$mail->setFrom ( 'support@mysite.net', 'MySite.net' );
$mail->addTo ( $email, $email );
$mail->setSubject ( 'test' );
$mail->send ();
```

If the user has another email provider the email is not sent.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you checked the spam folder?

Comment: Yes, empty :( hotmail.com and gmail.com work but gmx.de and web.de not. you can check it out, http://www.geldonkel.net/registration/register , it is a little zendf project of mine, it is not finished yet^^

Comment: why you don't use Zend's SMTP Class instead of the default (MAIL function)

Comment: never used it, do you have a example, link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use smtp now and it works:

```
 $config = array('auth' => 'login',
                    'username' => '****@gmail.com',
                    'password' => '****',
                    'port' => '25',
                    'ssl' => 'tls');


 $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.googlemail.com', $config);
```